# Add headers to Google Spreadsheet chart

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-charts

I have a chart in a spreadsheet. If I click on it and select 'advanced edit' > Start,
it offers to 'Use row 12 as headers'. How can I use a different row for the header names?
My data has rows for the headers, some rows of old data I dont want displayed, the data (which starts at row 12).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes. On that same tab there is a selection for **Data Select Ranges**

[image]

On the popup, choose your HEADER row first. This is important. Then click on **add another range**.
[image]

Now choose your data. Click Ok

Under "combine ranges" choose **vertically**.

Make sure the box is checked that says "use row XX as a header". (this would be the first range you chose).

I think that is what you are looking for.

Comment: @William: It only works if you put your header row first in the textbox, so you may have to change `Results!K77:P77, Results!K1:P1` to `Results!K1:P1, Results!K77:P77`.